# My domain www.digitalproductshopping.com is on a WordPress installation, Can I add a sub-directory that is html5

Tags: html, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

Can I have a HTML5 Sub Directory as part of my WordPress installation. I have put the subdirectory in  public.html folder, but when i enter the URL `www.digitalproductshopping.com/affiliatemoneysecret`, I get a page not found 404 error on this URL.

Comment: this is because WP treats this URL as post name 'affiliatemoneysecret'

Comment: looks like your permalinks don't work
try resetting them or check if host has mod_rewrite off

Comment: Deep Kakkar, Should mod_rewrite be off or on, resetting permalinks is having no effect. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sub directory was different, not in spelling but in capitalisation, in different documents, subdirectories must be spelled and capitalised exactly the same or the above error occurs.
Thanks for the effort everyone.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** create folder into your website directory ...parallel with folders : "wp-content" , "wp-admin" and "wp-includes"[image]

**Step 2** access your html page by www.yoursitename.com/folder where you can add html file and also run [image]

Comment: vrejesh, I have that folder and its name is "affiliatemoneysecret" is that what you mean. That contains images folder, index.html, downloadpage.html and a pdf file. Do I need anything else in that folder Thanks for the input

Comment: Is that folder on same location as suggested by @vrejesh ?

Comment: just access folder as per step 2 in my answer

Comment: @mbannist : please make my answer as solution by tick right beside my answer thx....

Comment: sorry, but this is what i had to begin with and the instruction that came with the package, i think. What does the folder your referring to contain in addition to the files i previously mentioned. Sorry to be a pain but my programming skills are limited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically due to .htacess rewrite rule
1)Try adding

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

to your htacess file , in most of the cases this should work if not then try adding

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname1/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname2/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

Comment: Swapnil Ghone, Is there a particular place to put these lines of code or at the beginning or end will do. Thank you for your input

Comment: try adding at the end , most probably "ErrorDocument 401 default" will resolve your issue .
If not then go for second solution

Comment: After putting in the second option I am getting an Error 404 - Oage not found.